# Reg. Meta Tags for SEO

Tags: seo, search-engine, meta-tags

Can anyone tell me the meta tags that should be included in a page for SEO friendly? Is this meta tags throughout same for all the pages of a site or differs from page to page? **[EDIT]** Also can anyone tell me the steps I've to do for my site to better SEO friendly like registering my domain in some websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is really a very broad question.

To start with the first part of your question: at least DIFFERENT meta tags per page for:

- title
- keywords
- description

Apart from that, it depends a bit on the search engine. If you are looking for Google I suggest you watch their series on Youtube where they provide excellent information.
http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp

Other things to investigate are:

- writing just plain good content
- valid and semantic html (use H1, H2,  etc. properly)
- alt tags for your images
- search engine friendly URL s

Answer (score 0):

The only true purpose for meta tags is the description tag, what you put here will be used in the search engine result. The other tags may help you with smaller search engines, but it won't really make a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've nearly completed the coding for my technical blog and looking for how I can make it more SEO optimized. As the first thing I thought of adding the necessary meta tags.Can I get some references?

Answer (score 0):

**i have used this snipped in my last project and this give me an up points for seo analize**

```html
 <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#73590A">
        <meta name=”description” content="Describe your page/site" />
        
        <!-- meta for social net openGraphic-->
        <meta property="og:title" content="same title">
        <meta property="og:description" content="same descripition">
        <meta property="og:image" content="link for image">
        <meta property="og:url" content="link for site/page">
       
      
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="link for icon" type="image/x-icon">
    
        
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
```